# SQL Server 2019 using Linked server to Oracle 19c (19.9) using Oracle 19c client on Windows - DBCOLUMNFLAGS_ISNULLABLE error

Tags: linked-server, sql-server-2019

Having issues selected data for some Oracle tables over the linked server from SQL Server:

```
select type, count(*) from RMTDB..JOB1308.HOST_INTERFACE group by type order by 1 desc;
```

> Msg 7356, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
> The OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "RMTDB" supplied inconsistent metadata for a column. The column "CREATE_TIME" (compile-time ordinal 3) of object ""JOB1308"."HOST_INTERFACE"" was reported to have a "DBCOLUMNFLAGS_ISNULLABLE" of 0 at compile time and 32 at run time.

Open query version of it works:

```
select * from OPENQUERY( RMTDB, 'select type, count(*) from HOST_INTERFACE group by type order by 1 desc')
```

result

```
TYPE      COUNT(*)
10          10450
8            6543
6            21
```

Anyone run into this?

Comment: What is the definition of HOST_INTERFACE in Oracle?  What version of Oracle's OleDB provider are you using?

Comment: I am using Oracle 19c windows client - freshly downloaded.

Comment: SQL> describe host_interface
 Name              Null?    Type
 ---------------- -------- -------------------------------------------------
 MESSAGE_ID        NUMBER(9)
 TYPE              NUMBER(8)
 CREATE_TIME       TIMESTAMP(6) WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE
 READ_TIME         TIMESTAMP(6) WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE
 STATUS            NUMBER(9)
 STATUS_DETAILS    VARCHAR2(1000)
 RECEIVER          NUMBER(9)
 PAYLOAD           CLOB

Comment: This view works ok:   SQL> describe V_INVENTORYSTACKS;
 Name                  Null?    Type
 --------------------- -------- -------
 STACK                 NOT NULL NUMBER(3)
 ROBOT_ZONE            NOT NULL NUMBER(2)
 SKU                   NOT NULL NUMBER(12)
 SKU_DESCRIPTION       VARCHAR2(40)
 STATE                 VARCHAR2(8)
 LOCK_BOTTOM_LAYER     NOT NULL NUMBER(1)
 REQUEST               NOT NULL NUMBER(7)
 LAYERS                NOT NULL NUMBER(2)
 LOT                   VARCHAR2(10)
 MEASURE               NOT NULL NUMBER(1)
 EMPTY                 NOT NULL NUMBER(1)

Answer (score 0):

I found a support.oracle.com Doc ID 1519958.1 that describes the issue.
For solution it says: Use the relatively simple work around of linking to a view that is based upon the table, instead of directly to the table.

Apparently this issue has been around since 2012.